# Javascript Regular expression for format 'hh:mm tt'

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match time in format 'hh:mm tt' 
example to match:

```
01:00 am
01:10 Pm
02:20 PM
```

i tried like this:

```
/^\d{2}:\d{2}:\s[a-z]$/.test('02:02 am')
```

Comment: You have an extra `:` to begin with...

Comment: Use a regexp testing site to test your regexps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat `[a-z]` exactly two times and also you need to add case-insensitive `i` modifier. And also remove the colon which exists before `\s`.

```
/^\d{2}:\d{2}\s[a-z]{2}$/i.test('02:02 am')
```

or

```
/^\d{2}:\d{2}\s[ap]m$/i.test('02:02 am')
```